# GeoTools convert albers projection to image X,Y

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

The other company that has worked with the exact same map as I use, used to do this with GDAL in C++, but I need to do this in Java and I didn't really want to use GDAL for Java because it is a lot of work to set up and I don't really have the time for this while I have GeoTools which looks like a good option.

They told me they did it like this:

> We use the GDAL/OGR libraries to handle the mapping between lat/lon,
>   projected x/y and screen x/y coordinates
>
> Each map is tuned to the exact location of each home-point, to limit
>   distortion.  All map projections use some sort of flat surface, which
>   means they all have some sort of distortion, because it does not match
>   the Earth's curvature everywhere.
>
> Abers' Conical Equal Area uses a cone that touches the Earth's surface
>   at 2 latitudes, which we set by default to be 1 degree north and south
>   of the radar.  This gives the region near the home-point the least
>   amount of distortion.  We do this for virtually all our home-point
>   sites for all customers.
>
> We could create one map projection for both.  However, we would have
>   to deliver a new set of topography maps.  If you want to combine data
>   from both home-points, you will need to define 3 OGRSpatialReferences;
>   one for lon/lat, one for the first point site, and one for the second
>   point site.  Then you can convert all points on both images to
>   lon/lat.  Alternatively, you can define the first OGRSpatialReference
>   as any destination projection you like.

Now, how can I do the same thing with GeoTools? Is there a way to do this?

This is their OGC WKT they use to project X/Y:

```
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.2572235629972,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",31.996308],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",33.996308],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",32.996308],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",35.415901],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
```

What I have tried is loading the WKT and creating a default reference and then doing a MathTransform:

```
    CoordinateReferenceSystem defaultCrs = org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
    CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.parseWKT("PROJCS[\"unnamed\", GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\", DATUM[\"WGS_1984\", SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.2572235629972, AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]], PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0], UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433], AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]], PROJECTION[\"Albers_Conic_Equal_Area\"], PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_1\",31.996308], PARAMETER[\"standard_parallel_2\",33.996308], PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_center\",32.996308], PARAMETER[\"longitude_of_center\",35.415901], PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0], PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0], UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]]]");
    MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(defaultCrs, crs, false);

    double[] dest = new double[2];
    transform.transform(new double[] {34.0, 35.0}, 0, dest,  0, 1);

    System.out.println(dest[0] + " " + dest[1]);
```

But then I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: Bursa wolf parameters required.
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperationStep(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:1082)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperationStep(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:1146)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperationStep(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:891)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperationStep(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:975)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:262)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.java:258)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.findMathTransform(CRS.java:1205)
    at org.geotools.App.main(App.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. You have told us what the other company does, but haven't told us what you've tried.  Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried and what you're stuck with.

Comment: Please think of merging your accounts: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

The important part of the error message is `Bursa wolf parameters required`.

So searching for that on the web will lead you to http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/faq.html#q-bursa-wolf-parameters-required with this solution:

```
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
```